# How to change Lightning:Tab label dynamically?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura, lightning-tab

I want to change label for tab dynamically, but that's not working.
Please find the related code below:

**Component**

```
<lightning:tab label="test1" id="tabId">
```

**JS Controller**

```
component.find("tabId").set('v.label', 'test2');
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it's not working? Any errors? Or is it simply not changing the label?

Comment: Yeah when I am trying to change the label using component.find(), its changing value to null. As we are using id instead of aura:id. Will that make any difference?

Comment: yes, `component.find` only works on `aura:id`, it does not work on the standard html `id` property

Comment: what about the id then? How can I change the value for label dynamically ?

Comment: @SankalpGupta as Sebastian said, use `aura:id` instead of `id`.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I tried that also, still not working. My label is changing to blank after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the `label` attribute in [`lightning:tab`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/specification) is of type `component[]` and not text. And thus it was not being set in the first place when trying to set the `label` directly.

```
component.find("tabId").set("v.label", "New Value");
```

So to set the `label`, you will need to get the `label` component and then set the `value` attribute on it. Note that you will need to use `aura:id` instead of `id` as mentioned in the docs.

This will yield you the results.

```
// this returns the tab's label component as an array
var tabLabel = component.find("tabId").get("v.label");

// this was to verify, where is the label's value set.
// the 0-th element in the label component has an attribute value
console.log(tabLabel[0].get("v.value")); 

// once you change it, your new label will be rendered righ away
tabLabel[0].set("v.value", "New Label");
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

While not completely sure about your use case, but re-rendering the tab will achieve for what you are looking for.

On Component, declare attributes as below:

```
<aura:attribute name="tabLabel" type="String" default="Old Label" />
<aura:attribute name="hasLabelChanged" type="Boolean" default="true" />
```

Then, use it as below to render the tab:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.hasLabelChanged}">
    <lightning:tab label="{!v.tabLabel}" aura:id="tabId">
        Tab Contents here !
    </lightning:tab>
</aura:if>
```

And then in your JS, doing something will let you change the `label`.

```
component.set("v.hasLabelChanged", false);
component.set("v.tabLabel", "New Label");
component.set("v.hasLabelChanged", true);
```